# Open the terminal on the guest OS from Host OS

Tags: 14.04, virtualbox, gnome-terminal

Guest OS - Ubuntu 14.04

Host Os - Ubuntu 14.10

Is it possible to open the `gnome-terminal` on the guest OS from the host OS? By `ssh`, we can access the terminal of the guest OS on the host OS itself. But I want something which opens up the terminal as a separate application on the guest OS.

Comment: Does the guest OS have an X server running?

Comment: What I mean is, does it have a GUI running? You can check: `pgrep -fa X`

Comment: @muru when I run the command. I am getting something [like this](http://imgur.com/ZBZEDJh)

Comment: You could have used SSH to run that command and copy pasted the output. At any rate, yes you have an X server running, so Sylvain's answer is correct. The important thing to note is the `:0` in the result. In Sylvain's command, you have to use `DISPLAY=:a.b`, and the `a` can obtained from that command.

Comment: @prodicus: Did you test my command? Does it work for you?

Comment: @muru I tried the command but nothing happened. I have given my response on Sylvain's answer.

Answer (score 1):

If your guest OS is running a Desktop session (i.e X server started), you could use the following command to open a terminal.

From your Host OS, open a terminal and type:

```
ssh <user>@<ip_of_guest> DISPLAY=:0.0 gnome-terminal
```

Just replace `<user>` and `<ip_of_guest>` with your real username and guest ip.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply guys. Had some connectivity issues. I tried it but [nothing happened, The terminal didn't open](http://imgur.com/0hxV9l2). But I am able to ssh into my virtual box. I tried running **gnome-terminal** from the ssh session but again got an error.

Comment: @prodicus: The first command (the one from my answer) should have opened a gnome-terminal in your VM. Needless the ssh again into the VM and type `gnome-terminal`. Your second command won't work. Please start the VM and type in the host the command of my answser. Then check that a new terminal was created in the VM. You really don't need to ssh into it.